# Does NLM_F_DUMP on AF_XDP support filtering?

Tags: linux, sockets, netlink, xdp-bpf

I'm issuing a `SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY` `DLM_F_DUMP` on a `NETLINK_INET_DIAG` netlink socket for the `AF_XDP` family. I successfully get back a dump of the currently open XSKs. So I think I got the basics correct it seems.

Now I want to query in some situations for a single specific XSK. For instance, for TCP sockets, certain fields of the request message are then populated with non-zero values to turn on filtering.

However, trying to do so with a dump request for `AF_XDP` sockets using the inode number and/or socket cookie always gets ignored and a full dump is returned. I've thus looked into the Linux kernel's v6.2 implementation of [`xsk_diag.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/xdp/xsk_diag.c#L148) and `xsk_diag_dump` in particular: if I'm not mistaken, then there is no filtering present.

This is the [code to serialize the XSK dump request](https://github.com/thediveo/netlink/blob/feature/sock-diag/socket_xdp_linux.go#L27), including the fields I would expect to be used for filtering:

```golang
type xdpSocketRequest struct {
    Family   uint8
    Protocol uint8
    pad      uint16
    Ino      uint32
    Show     uint32
    Cookie   [2]uint32
}

func (r *xdpSocketRequest) Serialize() []byte {
    b := writeBuffer{Bytes: make([]byte, sizeofSocketRequest)}
    b.Write(r.Family)
    b.Write(r.Protocol)
    native.PutUint16(b.Next(2), r.pad)
    native.PutUint32(b.Next(4), r.Ino)
    native.PutUint32(b.Next(4), r.Show)
    native.PutUint32(b.Next(4), r.Cookie[0])
    native.PutUint32(b.Next(4), r.Cookie[1])
    return b.Bytes
}
```

Can others please confirm or invalidate my understanding? Is filtering XSK dumps currently not supported at all?